# How can I run pip install package before the packages from requirements.txt are installed automatically on Heroku build?

Tags: heroku, pip, saml, requirements.txt

I have a Python Django project where the master branch is auto-deployed to Heroku. According to the build logs;

first, the **buildpacks** are used, then the **dependencies** are installed, after this packages from **requirements.txt** are installed.

For my SAML authentication to work, I have noticed on localhost that this is the only order of installation that works:

```
pip install python3-saml
pip install --force-reinstall --use-pep517 lxml lxml
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Here is what I tried:
Attempt 1:

1. Had the rest of the packages in requirements.txt, which were installed on auto-deploy
2. Next tried to install python3-saml and lxml (using the same --use-pep517 argument) on heroku bash

failed to build xmlsec wheel and the execution ended

Attempt 2:

1. Changed the Procfile to add the last line:

> web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi --log-file -
> jobs: python jobs.py
> release: pip install python3-saml && pip install --force-reinstall --use-pep517 lxml lxml && pip install -r requirements.txt

**Build logs** show that all other packages were installed and build was succeeded.

**Release logs** show that xmlsec wheel failed and this deployment failed.

I am trying to find a way to install my packages in that order to avoid this issue, or please also suggest if there is something else I can do in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: "first, the buildpacks are used, then the dependencies are installed, after this packages from requirements.txt are installed"—this is not correct. The buildpack takes care of building your application. It kicks off dependency installation, but that's _part of_ the buildpack behaviour, not after it. And dependencies are installed _using_ your `requirements.txt`. They're the same thing. (Unless you're using Pipenv, in which case your `Pipfile.lock` will be used and anything in your `requirements.txt` will be ignored. But either way, there's no "dependencies, then requirements.txt" flow.)

Comment: You should never have to `--force-reinstall` anything on Heroku. Can you explain why you think you need to do these three steps in that order? Why can't you just include `python3-saml` and `lxml` in your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Here is what the READme says "To avoid libxml2 library version incompatibilities between xmlsec and lxml it is recommended that lxml is not installed from binary.

This can be ensured by executing: $ pip install --force-reinstall --no-binary lxml lxml"

Comment: When I run this using `--no-binary`: DEPRECATION: lxml is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because the `--no-binary` option was enabled for it and this currently disables
local wheel building for projects that don't have a 'pyproject.toml' file. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the `--
use-pep517` option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11451